# How to get rows with a bit typed fields from mysql in node.js?

Tags: mysql, node.js

I am using a mysql npm package for connection and trying to get data from table, which has columns with type BIT.
But these columns have gone as:

```
"isBasic": {
      "type": "Buffer",
      "data": [
        1
      ]
    },
```

How can I map them to boolean type?

Comment: maybe by `!!data[0]`, in javascript if i understand correctly, else you can do it directly in mysql, e.g `SELECT field=1 AS boolean`

Comment: this doesn't work, check my answer below

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The bit data type is not perfectly used in mysql package. We usually use tinyint in tables to store 0 and 1 and then just do the comparison in Javscript to determine true or false.

Answer (score 10):

This may be late, but there is a way to cast BIT fields to booleans right when you define the connection (or pool):

```
var pool = mysql.createPool({
    "connectionLimit": process.env.MYSQL_LIMIT,
    "user": process.env.MYSQL_USER,
    "password": process.env.MYSQL_PASSWORD,
    "database": process.env.MYSQL_DATABASE,
    "host": process.env.MYSQL_HOST,
    "port": process.env.MYSQL_PORT,
    "typeCast": function castField( field, useDefaultTypeCasting ) {

        // We only want to cast bit fields that have a single-bit in them. If the field
        // has more than one bit, then we cannot assume it is supposed to be a Boolean.
        if ( ( field.type === "BIT" ) && ( field.length === 1 ) ) {

            var bytes = field.buffer();

            // A Buffer in Node represents a collection of 8-bit unsigned integers.
            // Therefore, our single "bit field" comes back as the bits '0000 0001',
            // which is equivalent to the number 1.
            return( bytes[ 0 ] === 1 );

        }

        return( useDefaultTypeCasting() );
    }
});
```

This was adapted from this article: https://www.bennadel.com/blog/3188-casting-bit-fields-to-booleans-using-the-node-js-mysql-driver.htm

Comment: This solution worked, I applied at a high level in Lambda and getting results correctly.

Comment: Elegant solution for different type of data type also its good to manage at this pace.

Answer (score 5):

Here is how you can read type=BIT value:

```
bit.lastIndexOf(1) !== -1
```

I've tested with true and false values:

```
console.log(bit, ' ----> ', bit.lastIndexOf(1) !== -1);
console.log(bit, ' ----> ', bit.lastIndexOf(1) !== -1);

// out:   <Buffer 01> ' ----> ' true
// out:   <Buffer 00> ' ----> ' false
```

And **another way** is to add transformation into SQL query:

```
mysql_connection.query('SELECT *,field_name=1 as field_name ...
```

and field_name's value will be 1 if true and 0 for false.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, i have is_success field and I'm using raw sequelize query and casting to unsigned. 
I'm getting

```
is_success: {
type: "Buffer",
data: [1]
}
```

to solve this i'm using casting 
`SELECT created_at as`date`, resource_type, (is_success + 0) as state ...`

This article has given a detailed description.
https://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/04/11/bit-values-in-mysql/

Answer (score 1):

I know it's a workaround, but I use this queries when working with BIT types instead of booleans.

```sql
SELECT *, (processed = 1) AS processed FROM ...
```